# Mean anomaly hyperbolic orbit

Tags: orbital-motion

What does the mean anomaly mean in a hyperbolic orbit? How, knowing the mean anomalies at two points along the hyperbolic orbit, do you calculate the time to travel between the two points on the orbit? I know how to do this for elliptical orbits, but there is no orbital period for hyperbolic orbits.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Hyper/parabolic Kepler orbits and “mean anomaly”](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/191971/hyper-parabolic-kepler-orbits-and-mean-anomaly)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The hyperbolic mean anomaly is defined by $$M = e\sinh H -H$$ This is very much analogous to the elliptical mean anomaly $$M = E - s\sin E$$

Just as the elliptical mean anomaly varies linearly with time, so does the hyperbolic mean anomaly. Just as the eccentric anomaly $E$ is related to the true anomaly $f$ via $$\tan\frac f 2 = \sqrt{\frac {1+e} {1-e}} \tan \frac E 2$$ the hyperbolic anomaly $H$ is related to the true anomaly $f$ via $$\tan\frac f 2 = \sqrt{\frac {e+1} {e-1}} \tanh \frac H 2$$